# AutoIt: run a program selected with FileOpenDialog?

Tags: scripting, autoit

I need to make a script that allows a user to run a software with certain parameters (that should be typed in). So, first step, select the exe. Second, a text input box should allow the user to enter the parameters. I can't get the first step done.

I tried with the second example found here: [FileOpenDialog](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/FileOpenDialog.htm)

The only modification is a `Run` command I added. When I run the script, I see the complete file path for the executable but nothing runs. I don't see an error either:

```
include <FileConstants.au3>
include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>

Example()

Func Example()
    ; Create a constant variable in Local scope of the message to display in FileOpenDialog.
    Local Const $sMessage = "Select a single file of any type."

    ; Display an open dialog to select a file.
    Local $sFileOpenDialog = FileOpenDialog($sMessage, @WindowsDir & "\", "All (*.*)", $FD_FILEMUSTEXIST)
    If @error Then
        ; Display the error message.
        MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "", "No file was selected.")

        ; Change the working directory (@WorkingDir) back to the location of the script directory as FileOpenDialog sets it to the last accessed folder.
        FileChangeDir(@ScriptDir)
    Else
        ; Change the working directory (@WorkingDir) back to the location of the script directory as FileOpenDialog sets it to the last accessed folder.
        FileChangeDir(@ScriptDir)

        ; Replace instances of "|" with @CRLF in the string returned by FileOpenDialog.
        $sFileOpenDialog = StringReplace($sFileOpenDialog, "|", @CRLF)

        ; Display the selected file.
        MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "", "You chose the following file:" & @CRLF & $sFileOpenDialog)
    Run($sFileOpenDialog)
    EndIf
EndFunc   ;==>Example
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <FileConstants.au3>

Example()

Func Example()
    ; Create a constant variable in Local scope of the message to display in FileOpenDialog.
    Local Const $sMessage = "Select a single file of any type."

    ; Display an open dialog to select a file.
    Local $sFileOpenDialog = FileOpenDialog($sMessage, @WindowsDir & "\", "All (*.*)", $FD_FILEMUSTEXIST)
    If @error Then
        ; Display the error message.
        MsgBox(1, "", "No file was selected.")

        ; Change the working directory (@WorkingDir) back to the location of the script directory as FileOpenDialog sets it to the last accessed folder.
        FileChangeDir(@ScriptDir)
    Else
        ; Change the working directory (@WorkingDir) back to the location of the script directory as FileOpenDialog sets it to the last accessed folder.
        FileChangeDir(@ScriptDir)

        ; Replace instances of "|" with @CRLF in the string returned by FileOpenDialog.
        $sFileOpenDialog = StringReplace($sFileOpenDialog, "|", @CRLF)

        ; Display the selected file.
        MsgBox(1, "", "You chose the following file:" & @CRLF & $sFileOpenDialog)
    Run($sFileOpenDialog)
    EndIf
EndFunc   ;==>Example
```

This works for me.
I dont know this "include MsgBoxConstants.au3" wich i think is unnecessary.

Lg Teifun2

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `#` before the include. Also the 2nd include has to be `Constants.au3`. When I do these changes I can successfully start any application with your code.

```
#include <FileConstants.au3>
#include <Constants.au3>
```